# Matlab: copy array in file txt

Tags: arrays, matlab, file, copy, wave

I want to copy elements of an array in a file txt. I read the first 50 samples of a wav file in array a and I want to copy a in a file txt. This is my code:

```
[s,fs]=wavread('file.wav');
for k=1:50
    a=s(k)
end

fid = fopen('file.txt','wt');

fprintf(fid,'%f\n',a);
fclose(fid);
```

With this code in file txt there is only the last element of a, not all samples.

Comment: Replace the loop by `a = s(1:50);`

Comment: That's because you only call `fprintf` ***one*** time, and at that point in the code, `a` contians the last sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fprintf`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) can process vector input. So you can simply replace the loop by `a = s(1:50);`:

```
[s,fs]=wavread('file.wav');
a = s(1:50);
fid = fopen('file.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid,'%f\n',a);
fclose(fid);
```